# React UseState changes value second time not first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

In react Project i have a list of subjects when a subject is clicked the videos regarding that subject is to be fetched

but when i click on the subject data is fetched properly but the data is not getting reflected in the web page though the console.log prints the data correctly

but when another subject is clicked it shows the data of the previously selected subject....

EG:
-> Maths subject clicked -> no changes in web page
-> English(any other) subject is clicked -> now it shows the data of the maths subject

```
// get the list of unique Subjects
  const getAllSubCategories = async (filterCategory = '') => {
    try {
      const filterCategory = fullUserInfo?.st_level

      let subjectList = await getVideoSubjects(filterCategory)
      subjectList = subjectList.data

      setSubCategoryListForSidebar(subjectList)
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error)
    }
  }
```

```
const fetchAllVideosByLevel = async (subject) => {
    let level
    if (userInfo && userInfo?.userType === 'Student') {
      level = fullUserInfo?.st_level
    } else if (userInfo && userInfo?.userType === 'Teacher') {
      level = fullUserInfo?.tc_level
    } else {
      level = 'JHS'
    }

    try {
      let response = await getVideosByLevel(level, userInfo?.userType, subject)
      // let { videoData } = response.data
      let newVideoData = response.data.videoData
      console.log('Video :', newVideoData)
      setVideoData([...newVideoData])
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error)
    }
  }
```

```
const handleSubjectChange = (e) => {
    var updatedList = []
    if (e.target.checked) {
      updatedList = [e.target.value]
    }
    console.log('list : ', updatedList)
    fetchAllVideosByLevel(updatedList[0])
    setSubject(updatedList)
  }
```

```
{subCategoryListForSidebar &&
                      subCategoryListForSidebar.map((item, i) => (
                        <label key={i}>
                          <input
                            className="subjects"
                            type="radio"
                            name="subject"
                            value={item}
                            onChange={(e) => handleSubjectChange(e)}
                          />
                          <span className="name">{item}</span>
                        </label>
                      ))}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `getAllSubCategories` ?

Comment: What specifically are you expecting to change?  This line? `<span className="name">{item}</span>`